# c++ displaying single dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having an issue compiling my program that displays information about the class "Horse". I am having the problem when I try to display the information.

```
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
              cout << ahorse[i].print() ;
              };
```

ahorse is an instance of class Horse. the class Horse looks like this:

```
class Horse{
  private:
          string name ;
          int lane;
          double time;
  public:
          Horse(string hname , int hlane , double htime){
                       name = hname ;
                       lane = hlane ;
                       time = htime;
                       };
          Horse(){
                  name = "" ;
                  lane = 0 ;
                  time = 0 ;
                  };

          void setname(string hname){
               name = hname;
               };
          void setlane(int hlane){
               lane = hlane;
               };
          void settime(double htime){
               time = htime;
               };

          string getname (){
                 return name ;
                 };
          int getlane(){
                 return lane;
                 };
          double gettime(){
                 return time;
                 };




          void print(){
               cout << "Horse Name: " << name << endl;
               cout << "Horse Lane: " << lane << endl;
               cout << "Horse Time: " << time << endl;

               };       
                  };
```

the print() function looks like this inside the class Horse:

```
void print(){
               cout << "Horse Name: " << name << endl;
               cout << "Horse Lane: " << lane << endl;
               cout << "Horse Time: " << time << endl;
```

name, lane, and time are private variables that store name, lane, and time, respectively

Comment: What does Horse::print returns? Does it actually print horse's information or it returns some data to be printed?

Comment: What is the compiler error/errors?

Comment: print() function returns void. so you just need to use `ahorse[i].print()` instead of `cout << ahorse[i].print()`.

Comment: the error is no match for 'operator<<'in 'std::cout<<, to paraphrase, I know it is way longer, but I can't get the entire error out of my compiler

Comment: You don't need semicolons after defining functions. Your print function already prints. See the answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << ahorse[i].print() ;
    };
```

To

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            ahorse[i].print() ;
        };
```

`Horse::print()` Returns void so there is nothing to print.

Comment: Thanks! I feel a little silly not catching that, I am still learning C++, obviously, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't feel silly every one has trouble learning a complex language like c++. Also if my answer helped you please up vote and accept the answer.